# The plug-in for datatables - datatables column filter

Tags: jquery

Has someone used the jQuery table - DataTables before?(https://datatables.net/usage/)

There's a plug-in called DataTables column filter for this. However, when i use server-process, it just keeps showing "processing", I have checked through tools of chrome and found out that it did not send a POST to server. I'm wondering whether it's too old and the new DataTables has changed a lot of thing, which make this plug-in could not send a POST correctly?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Datatables itself offers various search filtering for columns, like listed below:

[Basic Explanation](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/), [Regex (best in my opinion)](http://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html), [Input Multi-Filter](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html), [Select Multi-Filter](http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html), [Range Search](http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html).

They do work with server-side data. Pick the best one and enjoy.